# Click on div using jquery error

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="divHolder">
   <a href="./"><img src="./images/image6.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div class="divHolder">
   <a href="./IT.aspx"><img src="./images/image7.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript I have:

```
$('.divHolder').click(function () {

    var link = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    if (link != null) {
         location.href = link;
    }
});
```

However, every time I click on a div, the href of the div is always the last one: for example in this case is: IT.aspx.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Its working fine for me... Check http://jsfiddle.net/BSZF7/

Comment: Hmm. Works for me, apart from that `link` is of course never `null`. Have you tried `alert` ing `link` rather than immediately forwarding to it? I'm just wondering whether it's just that the default page, if that's the correct term, is `IT.aspx` and essentially in the first instance all you're doing is stripping the url down to the last directory which will then load the default page in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be the following

```
$('.divHolder:has(a)').click(function () {
  location.href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

Comment: I find it strange, but I fixed this problem in my javascript. Thanks!